# Windows 8 Stutters / Lags on Video Playback

Tags: windows-8, lag, video-playback

Ever Since i switched to Windows 8 i have been facing issues this is one of the most annoying issues i am having
Whenever i play uncompressed files Made from FRAPS / DXTORY the video stutters with Choppy audio with it
tried VLC / Media player/ Media player classic / KLITE MEGA CODEC PACK / SHARK 007 Windows 8 Codecs
nothing Helped

Another Issue is When i Try To Play HTML 5 video on VIMEO using GOOGLE CHROME the video stutters with choppy audio similarly like uncompressed videos which i mentioned above
but the Same video with Flash Player works fine

I am totally out of ideas and solution or i will have to switch back to windows 7 i have tried old and new NVIDIA DRIVERS as well

My Pc Specs are

Intel i5 3570k
Asrock Z77 Extreme 6
8GB RAM
GTX 570 with Latest Drivers

Answer (score 2):

Have you downloaded the drivers compatible with windows 8 or are you using the windows 7 ones?

I was also having that issue and I had to reinstall the video card driver.

The solution that worked for me was to uninstall the graphics driver and let  windows update find and install graphics driver for me.

Comment: yes I am using NVIDIA DRIVERS FOR WINDOWS 7/8 with HIGH PERFORMANCE MODE
I will give a try to completely uninstall and LET WINDOWS UPDATE thing will report back after that